# write an equation of a line parallel to the given line through the given point

Tags: graphing-functions

write an equation of a line parallel e given line through the given point

$y=\frac{1}{2}(x-2)$ and point $(3,6)$ 
 I don't know how to do this I don't know what to try I feel hopeless

Comment: Your given line $y=\frac{1}{2}x-2$ has slope $\frac{1}{2}$. Any line parallel to this has slope $\frac{1}{2}$, and therefore equation of shape $y=\frac{1}{2}x+b$. To choose $b$ so the line goes through $(3,6)$, substitute. We get $6=\frac{1}{2}(3)+b$, so $b=\frac{9}{2}$. If your original line was $y=\frac{1}{2}(x-2)$, the slope is still $\frac{1}{2}$, so the solution and answer are the same.

Comment: I don't get it , so there is no answer

Comment: Sure there is an answer, and I gave it. It is $y=\frac{1}{2}x+b$, where $b=\frac{9}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of a line passing through a point $(a,b)$ and has a slope $m$ is
$$y-b=m(x-a)$$
and so simply you have 
$$y-6=\frac{1}{2}(x-3)\\
y=\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}+6\\
y=\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{9}{2}$$

Comment: so ummm can u explain that

Comment: @aalyb I did it

Comment: oh now I get it ... I think thanks im new to this site

Comment: So you accept my this answer, as always if you face any problem just let me know

Comment: but isn't supposed to be in y=mx+b form

Comment: you can use this form first put $m=\frac{1}{2}$ then use the point to get $b$. If you need to simplify the above result just move -6 to the opposite side

Comment: so its y=1/2x+6

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: I edited it, do you accept it?